# Random group allocation for a psychological experiment in python?

Tags: python, pandas, statistics

I am going to perform a motor learning experiment with random and blocked practice. I have a clustered sampling design where I sample different training groups (with app. 12 athletes in each group). I will perform a pre-test with the athletes from which I will perform the random allocation to the random and blocked group.

However, because I expect athletes within a group to have quite a range of performance, I need to perform a stratification on performance so I make sure that that the random and blocked group have app. an equal number of good and bad performers. To accomplish this, I have written a function in Python that first sort values in the 'performance' column on a dataframe from low to high. Then, it splits them into two groups, like in this figure:

[image: Split]
I have used the following Python code to accomplish this:

```
    @staticmethod
    def allokereIGrupper():
    df1 = groupby.sort_values(by='PRESTASJON', ascending=True)
    mask = np.arange(len(df1)) % 2
    global group1
    group1 = df1.loc[mask == 0]
    global group2
    group2 = df1.loc[mask == 1]
    return group1, group2
```

Now that I app. have an equal number of good and bad performers, I want to allocate the athletes within each group (group 1 and 2) to a random and a blocked group. I have used the python random sample() method to accomplish this. I have created two functions, one for each group.

```
    @staticmethod
    def velgerGR1():
    grupper = ['RANDOM', 'BLOCKED']
    for i in group1['BIB#'].unique():
        velger = random.sample(grupper, k=1)
    group1['GRUPPE'] = velger
    return group1

    @staticmethod
    def velgerGR2():
    grupper = ['RANDOM', 'BLOCKED']
    for i in group2['BIB#'].unique():
        velger = random.sample(grupper, k=1)
    group2['GRUPPE'] = velger
    return group2
```

The two staticmethods above creates a new column with the either RANDOM or BLOCKED. The next staticmethod simply select those athletes who have been assigned to a random and blocked group within each group and then concatenate them into a dataframe for random and a dataframe for blocked.

```
    @staticmethod
    def lageDataFrames():
    global dfJoinedRandom
    hentRandom = group1.query('GRUPPE == "RANDOM"')
    hentRandom2 = group2.query('GRUPPE == "RANDOM"')
    dfJoinedRandom = pd.concat([hentRandom, hentRandom2])

    global dfJoinedBlocked
    hentBlocked = group1.query('GRUPPE == "BLOCKED"')
    hentBlocked2 = group2.query('GRUPPE == "BLOCKED"')
    dfJoinedBlocked = pd.concat([hentBlocked, hentBlocked2])

    return dfJoinedRandom, dfJoinedBlocked
```

For me, this seems to work. My code is not returning any errors and I get two DataFrames with what I want. However, I wonder whether:

1. Is this a valid/good way of doing the random allocation?
2. Is there a better way of performing this task in Python?

For my statistical test, I am going to fit a multilevel regression model.

Cheers